# Erro ao comparar dois números

Tags: php

Estou tendo um problema ao comparar dois números, segue meu código:

```
// Valor
    $total_ch = 691.11;

    // Calcula valor total das contas a receber
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT SUM(valor) FROM contas_receber where status = '1' and id IN ($contas)");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $valor_contas =  $row['SUM(valor)'];

    // Verifica se o total dos cheques e maior que os das contas a receber
    if ($valor_contas > $total_ch) {
        // Exibe Alert
        echo "erro";
    }
```

O valor retornado de `$row['SUM(valor)']` é de 691.11. Logo, os dois valores são iguais, porém o sistema está apontando que valor de `valor_contas` é maior que o de `total_ch`.

O que está causando isso? Como resolver?

Comment: Pode ser que ele esteja arredondando o valor de `$valor_contas`. Mande a estrutura do BD. Outra coisa é que ele vai pegar o valor total de tudo que veio do select, então precisamos saber qual valor ele retorna.

Comment: Entendi. Bom o campo valor esta assim `valor decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL`. Eu mandei um echo nas duas variáveis, e o valor escrito na tela são iguais. isso que não estou entendendo.

Comment: Mas entra no if?

Comment: sim entra, e escreve `echo "erro";`

Comment: Dá um `var_dump()` nas duas variáveis.

Comment: No site do php explica alguma coisa sobre comparação de numeros float http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.float.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz o cast da string para float usando `(float)`, assim:

```
$valor_contas =  (float) $row['SUM(valor)'];
```